# Good pratice for naming multiple iteration counters

Tags: javascript, loops, iteration, counter

My question is about general good practices of naming multiple iteration counters in different functions. Let's assume that I have 3 different functions and each of them has `for` loop. In the 1st one i used `for(var i=0; i<5; i++)`
all other functions also hold similar `for` loop. Should I rather change `i` counter to `0` after each loop at the end of each function or declare 3 different variables as the iteration counter in each `for` loop within each function?

Comment: what speaks against naming them i??

Comment: sounds like you're using a global variable when it should be scoped

Comment: @MildlySerious Ok, thank you! That's right. I declare global i=0; so after each loop it permanently becomes i = x; after each loop. All is clear for me now. thank you.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I have 3 **different** functions

If it's three different functions, and you declare your loop `for (`**`var`**`i = 0)`, it will be a different *i* for each of these. In that case, `var` declares the variable within the function scope ([see MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/var)). So, *i* is a perfectly fine name (mostly, I see *i*, *j* and *k* for nested loops (*)) and there's no need for distinctions.

However: Without the `var`, if you're not in strict mode, *i* will have global scope.

As a side note: As of today (ES6), I would prefer using `for (`**`let`**`i = 0...`), if *i* is not used outside the loop, since in that case *i* is scoped to the loop ([MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let)).

---

(*) even though, if one needs three nested loops, something might be wrong.

Comment: Thank you :) You provide me more really valuable information! :)

Answer (score 2):

Unless the interaction inside each function somehow related they should be declared individually, regardless of name.

Also unless your using a global field for `i` each code blocks `i` variable is only in local scope anyway, so no need to reset anything.

Basically, I wouldn't share any variable for iteration specifically in global scope, I would move this looping functionality into it's own scoped function if appropriate.

Comment: Yeah, that was my problem indeed. I'll remember this now! Thank you very much :)

Comment: No worries. just noticed you were helped in the comments also, feel free to accept this as an answer, happy coding!

Comment: @Luke_Nuke Please ignore requests to accept an answer just 15 minutes after the question was posted; give people a chance to post their answers, then after you stop receiving answers, pick the best one.

Comment: @m69 36 I'm sorry I should do as you say. I'll remember about this in the future!

Comment: @Luke_Nuke No problem, I should've typed faster :-)

Comment: @m69 Was more of a suggestion in this context... https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/88539/248742

Comment: I understand, but new users often think they have to act immediately when getting such a suggestion. Feel free to make the suggestion, but maybe give it a couple of hours.

Comment: Sorry about the rep, I was only trying to delay the decision, not necessarily change it.